# update record issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update record in codeigniter, I can updated it statically like i give id=2,3,5 etc but i want to do dynamically and not want to use query params

this is my controller code:

```
function check(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('account', 'account', 'required');
    
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('forgotpassword');
        echo "please correctly fill the form";
    }else{
        $this->load->model('forgotpassword_model');
        if($this->forgotpassword_model->forgot_password() == 1){
            $data = array(
                'account' => rand(155555,508888),
            ); 
            $this->db->where('id',7);
            $this->db->update('login',$data);
            $this->load->view('forgotpassword');
            echo "successfully updated";
        }else{
            $this->load->view('forgotpassword');
            echo "invalid credentials";
        }
    }
    
}
```

like i gave id 7 but i don't want to give static id
i want to give id dynamic

Comment: can your problem is solved?

Comment: no it's not solved yet because i want my record's id from database

Comment: You can get  your `record's id` from database at edit update page view by `session`.

Comment: hey if this helped you please marked as accepted answer or upvote answer please.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT Page:-**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'Controler_Name/check ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//get edit and update id & make it hidden.

<input type="hidden" name="update_id" value="<?echo $update_id;?>">

</form>
```

**controller code:-**

```
function check(){
       
       $update_id = $this->input->post('update_id');

if($this->forgotpassword_model->forgot_password() == 1){
        
        $data = array(
            'account' => rand(155555,508888)
            );

            $this->db->where('id',$update_id );
            $this->db->update('login',$data);
            $this->load->view('forgotpassword');
            echo "successfully updated";
        }else{
            $this->load->view('forgotpassword');
            echo "invalid credentials";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a FORGOT PASSWORD page where you are asking your user to fill in some details. If details are correct, update record in database else throw an error. What I will suggest is to add a unique input feild (like username, userid, email or whatever you have there) (other than primary-key) and look for the record related to that unique feild. This way you can dynamically update the record.

**VIEW**

```
`<form action="your_action">
...
<input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="username, userid, email, mobile">
...
</form>`
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
...
$uid = $this->input->post ('uid');
$this->db->where ('your_feild_name', $uid);
$this->db->update ('your_table_name');
...
```

Comment: what if i want to fetch user id from database and update it?

Comment: @ipchirag - you can fetch user-id by taking input any other unique value for that user, fetch record and update it (if its not primarykey)